# Emacs C-j for elisp interaction

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm guessing that because I have Paredit running in Lisp Interaction it takes over C-j and makes it do standard RET-indent? I want it to evaluate and print last expression. Do I have to disable Paredit or can I have both Paredit and normal C-j eval-print behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the key in Paredit's map and rebind the Paredit command to another key.

```
  (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-j") nil)
  (define-key paredit-mode-map YOUR-KEY 'paredit-newline)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) as Paredit replacement.
It won't mess up <kbd>C-j</kbd> in `*scratch*`.